# I can't set 1280x1024 resolution in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, display, monitor

After installing a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC, Ubuntu can't detect my monitor which is a Phillips 190c 19".

With 10.10, I used 1280x1024 and on Nvidia drivers I was able to see my monitor brand. But on  12.04, I can only see `crt-0`. I also tried with the command `xrandr` to add a new mode without any success. See attached screen-shots. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. What is your driver version? Are you sure the driver is activate?